# ClickOnce のアプリケーションが特定の端末で動かない

Tags: .net

ClickOnce でブラウザからアプリを起動しています。通常の端末ではうまくいっています。

しかし、ドメインに入っているセキュリティの堅い端末では、ブラウザからの起動時に、xxx.applicaton [appliction manifest] の「名前を付けて保存」ダイアログがでてきてしまいます。

端末設定が問題だと思うんですが、何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: @satさん、問題が発生している状況に関してもう少し詳細に情報をシェアしましょう。そうすることで問題がより具体的になり、よい解決策が見つかり易くなると思います。例えば、「通常の端末」とはどのような環境なのか、「セキュリティの堅い端末」はどのような環境なのかが判ると手掛かりが増えると思います。ヘルプセンターの「良い質問をするには？」も参考になると思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: .application ファイルの MIME タイプは、サーバー/クライアントともに "application/x-ms-application" になっていますか?  
  
 / 参照: 
MSDN 「[ClickOnce 配置でのサーバーおよびクライアント構成の問題](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms228998.aspx)」、 「[ClickOnce 配置のトラブルシューティング](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/fb94w1t5.aspx)」